# No Azure DevOps Pipelines - Builds - Tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Following this Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/getting-started-with-continuous-testing) ([Run unit tests with your builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/getting-started-with-continuous-testing)), I was expecting to be able to run my unit-tests automatically when a build is triggered, such as a Pull request.

However, when I look in the **Pipeline / Builds** tab and try to edit my pipeline, there is nothing that allows me to add a new task (see screenshot below).
[image]

However, there doesn't appear to be any way of adding a task. I can't even switch to the YMAL without navigating to the source via the Repo. I was hoping to use the GUI though as my YMAL is non-existent.

I have created a test solution with the following structure, which is held in the repo:

```
Core Solution
    |_ Class Library Project (.NET Core)
    |_ MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)
```

I was hoping to have a build step followed by a Unit Test step using the tests in my **MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)** project once they were built.

There appears to be a **Tasks** option in the **Releases** tab by the way, but I was expecting to be able to add tasks for builds as well, especially Unit Tests.

Being new at this, perhaps I have missed or misunderstood something. I would be grateful for any help and to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that there is an obscure link that takes you through to the correct process, found it quite by accident, see screenshot below:

[image: Choose the **Use the visual designer** option]

It turns out that there is a little link titled **Use the visual designer** that I'd missed. Seems a little odd that most of the tutorials discuss this process and yet it's partially obscured. I guess that this shows that the platform is a work in process and still being added to and improved.

Another few caveats for those descending this little rabbit hole, after selecting the **Use the visual designer** link, be sure to select the **Empty pipeline** template, or whatever is appropriate to your project/solution type, and not the **YAML** option at the top of the list, otherwise you'll be back where you started.

[image: Select the **Empty pipeline** template]

Finally, it seems that automated Unit Tests don't work on Agents other than **Hosted VS2017** Agents (that said, I haven't tried the **Hosted** option). This is set in the very next screen by selecting the **Pipeline** and selecting the **Agent pool** from the drop-down.

One last thing... The pipeline won't run automatically unless you check the **Enable continuous integration** checkbox on the **Triggers** tab.

Once this is all done, I simply chose the tasks needed for the build by clicking the plus symbol on the *Agent job 1* item.

Good luck

Kaine

Answer (score 2):

You have created a new YAML style of build configuration. Currently Azure DevOps does not support of having YAML & GUI editor at the same time (this is upcoming feature in Q1/2019).

To get a GUI editor, create new **build** pipeline.

In this selection click "Use the visual designer".

[image]

Then at template phase, don't select YAML. Any other template will do. You can easily delete all the build steps after selecting template, so don't be afraid to choose any.
[image]

Comment: I'm using dark theme in Azure DevOps, but don't mind about it :).

Comment: Hi @Mino, Yes I have just discovered that myself. Thanks ever so much for your response. You're very kind.